# meteor: how to add and use pagedown?

Tags: meteor, pagedown

I'm new to Meteor and I'm trying to figure out how to use [pagedown](https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) within Meteor.

I added the 3 main files (`Markdown.Converter.js, Markdown.Sanitizer.js and Markdown.Editor.js`) in `client/lib` but this does not work.

There is an error in the console:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Markdown is not defined in Markdown.Editor.js`

Looking at the code, `Markdown` is defined in `Markdown.Converter.js` and is needed in the 2 other files.

Also, I have noticed that the `Markdown.Converter.js` file I added in the `lib` folder is automatically edited. 
When I look at it in the browser when the page is rendered, the whole file has been encapsulated into `(function(){ ... })();`. Why?
I guess that explains why `Markdown` is not accessible in the other files anymore.

I'm missing something. How does this work?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding the package: https://atmospherejs.com/dwatson/meteor-pagedown instead of using the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @waffles mentions, use [the package](https://atmospherejs.com/dwatson/meteor-pagedown); or put the files in `client/compatibility`, not `client/lib`.

Comment: Ok thanks that seems to work, I'd like to understand why Meteor works this way though. 1) Why does meteor wrap up in a new variable scope what I put in `client/lib`? 2) What differences are there in putting my files in `client/compatibility` or using the package you mentionned? 3) How can I see the content (files) of a package? Thanks.

Comment: Meteor isn’t wrapping in a new variable scope, it’s just loading files in an order different than what you’re expecting. See the section in the docs about [file load order](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp). `client/compatibility` loads earlier than any of your app’s files, hence the object is available before you try to call it. Packages are available even earlier, which is why they’re the best choice when available for your library. You can see the contents of a package by finding that package in `~/.meteor/packages`.

Comment: I don't think the problem was a problem of load order. I was not calling the object in my app. Here is what I understood: the `Markdown` object is defined in `Markdown.Converter.js` and is called in `Markdown.Editor.js`. I made sure that `Markdown.Converter.js` was loaded before `Markdown.Editor.js` but Meteor wrapped `Markdown.Converter.js` with `(function(){ ... })();` so the `Markdown` object was not in the global scope anymore, hence the error in `Markdown.Editor.js`. Thanks for the help.